# How to pass a template instance to a function that expects the template parameter to a a base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pointers

I'm not sure how to explain it because I don't really know the correct terms, but here is an example:

```
template <typename T>
struct PointerWrapper {
    T *ptr;
};

struct Base {};

struct Derived : public Base {};

void test(PointerWrapper<Base>) {}

int main() {
    PointerWrapper<Derived> p;
    test(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Since "Derived" is derived from "Base" and the "PointerWrapper" struct only works with pointers to the type specified by the template, there is nothing wrong with this. But the compiler complains:

```
asdfg.cpp:15:11: error: could not convert ‘p’ from ‘PointerWrapper<Derived>’ to ‘PointerWrapper<Base>’
```

I even tried `test(reinterpret_cast<PointerWrapper<Base>>(p))`, but it says:

```
asdfg.cpp:15:51: error: invalid cast from type ‘PointerWrapper<Derived>’ to type ‘PointerWrapper<Base>’
```

So what should I do?

Comment: You can't do this (easily). `PointerWrapper<A>` and `PointerWrapper<B>`are entirely different, unrelated types. At best you can implement something like `std::static_pointer_cast`, but that requires you to write some code.

Comment: What is static_pointer_cast? I cannot find it in any C++ reference sites. (and why did one of the answers just disappear?)

Comment: Take a look at a [real reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) :-) Anyway, the point is that you need to write the obvious conversion function yourself.

Comment: I did search that site and it shows no results: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=static_pointer_cast&go=Go). Anyway, I'm not using std::shared_ptr in this situation, so I don't see how it helps.

Comment: That was just an example to illustrate the point that you need to write something like `template <typename T, typename U> PointerWrapper<U> convert(PointerWrapper<T> const &)`. There should be an `std::is_base_of` trait check in there somewhere, or perhaps `std::is_constructible`.

Comment: I see now. But i already got the solution from ildjarn's answer: give PointerWrapper a constructor that takes a PointerWrapper of any type and casts the raw pointer. I guess it's a similar concept to your suggestion, but it doesn't require you to explicitly call any conversion functions when using PointerWrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PointerWrapper<Base>` and `PointerWrapper<Derived>` are utterly different types, despite the relationship between `Base` and `Derived`.

If you want to allow any `PointerWrapper<>` to be passed in, do:

```
template<typename T>
void test(PointerWrapper<T>)
{ }
```

If you want to allow only `PointerWrapper<T>` instances where `T` is derived from `Base`, do:

```
template<typename T>
void test(
    PointerWrapper<T>,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, void*>::type = 0
)
{ }
```

If you're using C++03, replace `std::` with `boost::` and get rid of `::value`.

Comment: OK, but what if you, for example, have a `std::vector<PointerWrapper<Base>>` and want to store PointerWrappers for various derived classes of Base in it?

Comment: @mtk358 : If that's your scenario, you should have mentioned it in the question. ;-] I don't have a good answer for that offfhand; refer to KerrekSB's comment.

Comment: I thought that it wasn't relavent since I thought that there was a way to either make the compiler know that it's safe or force the compiler to ignore the fact that the types are different (which is what I thought reinterpret_cast does).

Comment: @mtk358 : C++ is a strongly, statically typed language, and you're working with entirely different types. Putting a conversion constructor/operator inside of `PointerWrapper<>` is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I added `template <typename U> PointerWrapper(const PointerWrapper<U> &orig) : ptr(static_cast<T*>(orig.ptr)) {}` to PointerWrapper and now the example compiles.

Comment: @mtk358 : Be sure to add `enable_if` machinery similar to what's in my answer to your code if you want to enforce an inheritance relationship before casting (which would be a good idea for safety reasons and won't add any runtime overhead).

Answer (score 1):

you can do that :

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base {};

struct PointerWrapperBase {
    virtual Base* getBase() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct PointerWrapper : PointerWrapperBase {
    virtual Base* getBase() { return this->ptr; }
    T *ptr;
};

void test(PointerWrapperBase&) {}

int main() {
    PointerWrapper<Derived> p;
    test(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding a vtable defeats the purpose of using CRTP in the first place IMO, but +1 for a correct solution nonetheless.

Comment: But there is no CRTP here, is it?